# MAUI Shell navigation - nav stack replace and query parameters for each item of stack

Tags: shell, navigation, maui

we have a MAUI app and in some case i need to replace whole stack of navigation with data for each page. But it seems that only last element can get data from query. For example:

**await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//A/B/c/Detail?id=1");**

But i need data for each of page A,B,C for case when i go back  by ..

How can i achieve this?

Something like this **//A?id=2/B?id=3?**.... or **pass data when i make back button** ..?id=20

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Well you can create your Custom Base Page and in that have a virtual method for backward navigation something like how https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm does it

Comment: I updated the answer and added relevant code. You can check it.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, as you said that "only last element can get data from query". I created a project to try to achieve what you want but failed.

You can refer to the official doc about [syntax of Passing data when use Shell navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#pass-data).

In addition, you can check this [QuickStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows) by official. It also involves navigating with query parameter:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NoteEntryPage)}?{nameof(NoteEntryPage.ItemId)}={note.ID.ToString()}");
```

Wish it could be helpful to you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.